# How do I make a button slide to reveal like the UITableView delete confirmation button?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, core-animation

I would like to re-create the animation of the delete confirmation button that Apple uses in the default implementation of UITableView. I want to create this button and animation in my own custom view area, but haven't been successful in finding a proper view transition or animation. Here is a picture of the reveal animation half way through:

[image]

And here is a picture of the animation after it has finished:

[image]

These are screenshots from a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFxtZEW7Dis#t=290s) that shows how the button animation is supposed to look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically,
1) Put a button inside a view of the same size as the button, with the autoresizing masks of the button set to force it to not shrink when the view changes size, and have a left flexible margin.
2) Animate the view's frame to change from 0 width to full width while moving from x origin to (x - view width) origin.

As the view grows the button will be revealed.  The view should have clipToBounds set to yes.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I had been trying to do, but it wasn't working. I figured out finally what I had to do (this plus a bit extra). You have to set the button's `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` and then set the frame of the button to have an x-origin of -1 * the button width. Otherwise the button will never show up.

Comment: Definitely works with setting the button's origin to -1*button width, and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`